# Is the momentum operator well-defined in the basis of standing waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, operators, boundary-conditions, matrix-elements

Suppose I want to describe an arbitrary state of a quantum particle in a box of side $L$. The relevant eigenmodes are those of standing waves, namely 
$$ \left<x|n\right>=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\cdot \sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$
In this basis, the operate $\hat{p}^2$ is diagonal by construction, so every state has a definite energy.

But suppose I want to construct this operator from the matrix elements of $\hat{p}$? These are ($\hbar=1$)
$$\left<m|\hat{p}|n \right>=-\frac{2imn((-1)^{m+n}-1)}{L\cdot(m^2-n^2)}$$
which vanishes for $m$ and $n$ with the same evenness, making this an off-diagonal "checkered" matrix.

I tried taking a finite portion of this matrix and squaring it in order to obtain $\hat{p}^2$, but from what I could tell, this yields an on-diagonal checkered matrix, contrary to the construction that it would be strictly diagonal.

I assume this has something to do with the fact that the wavefunctions obtained by applying $\hat{p}$ do not satisfy the same boundary conditions as the basis functions (do not vanish). Would this problem be solved I had taken the the infinite matrix in its entirety before squaring? Or is this entire problem (decomposing $\hat{p}$ in this basis) ill-defined?

Comment: For an interesting take, see [Classical symptoms of quantum illnesses, C Zhu and J R Klauder, AjP 61 p 605](http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.17221).

Comment: Related: [What's the deal with momentum in the infinite square well?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362305/)

Comment: Your narrow technical problem is solved in [Prentis & Ty, *Am Jou Phys*  **82**, 583 (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.4864740). The fine answers below point out the standard pathologies. Infinite-Dimensional matrices and the tell-tale series are essential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hilbert space for a particle in a box has no associated momentum operator (as a momentum operator implies that the state space is invariant under space translations). So your attempt do define one leads to artifacts.

[Edit] In general, the Hamiltonian must be a densely defined operator on the physical Hilbert space. But a square well potential is too singular as an operator on the space of all square integrable functions on $R$ (i.e., no densely defined subspace is mapped by it into the Hilbert space), hence its Hilbert space cannot be the standard Hilbert space.

[Edit2] Note that the usual formula for the momentum is not a canonical momentum on the restricted space of wave functions defined only in the box, as it fails to satisfy either the commutation relation or does not preserve the boundary conditions.

The appropriate replacement for the momentum operator is the mode counting operator $\hat n$ with $\hat n|n\rangle=n|n\rangle$; see also the derivation of Qmechanic.

Comment: Shouldn't the momentum operator exist anyway, and any invariance of the Hamiltonian just imply that it (meaning its expected value) is conserved?

Comment: @BenjiRemez: see my edited answer. It is not about any invariance, it is about being able to define the translation as an operator in the same space. The translated potential lives in a different Hilbert space!

Comment: Alright, so here's a followup question. I agree that the mode counting operator produces equivalent information. But my problem is that these states do no distinguish between positive and negative momenta (they don't specify a sign). So, if I were to put wave packet in the box with some momentum, moving along, say, the positive $x$ axis, how would such a packet be decomposed in the basis of the eigenstates? And how would it differ if the initial momentum had been negative?

Comment: @BenjiRemez: There is no momentum, so the question is moot. Standing waves have no direction, so there sohouldn't be a sign.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: In no bound state the momentum has a certain value, but it does not mean it does not exist. Rather, it fluctuates. One can calculate its "variation" $\sqrt{\langle n|\hat p ^2|n\rangle - \langle n|\hat p|n\rangle ^2} $, can't one?

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski: If it were an observable with a continuous spectrum, it would have generalized eigenstates.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: And how about pressure that a confined particle develops on the walls?

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski: The notion of pressure requires a many-particle system, a notion of changing volume, and statistical mechanics. None of these is given here.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: Everything is here: reflection from a wall is a result of interaction with the wall material, one can calculate a transferred momentum averaged over many periods that is equivalent to an instant pressure in a many-particle system.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: You wrote: "the momentum ... does not preserve the boundary conditions." But inside the wall $\psi(x)=0$ and the momentum operator does not change this value. If you approach the boundary from the wall interior, the boundary value is zero. In the well the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian are always numerically different from $\hat p \psi_n (x)$, so what?

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski: There are two walls. If you translate to the right, the right boundary condition will be violated.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: Frankly, I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski: I expressed it globally rather than locally; momentum is infinitesimal translation. if $psi(x)=0$ it doesnt always imply that $\psi'(x)=0$. Thus $\hat p(x)$ is generally nonzero at the boundary.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: Momentum is a *generator* of translations. The latter can be infinitesimal or finite, whatever. It does not create difficulties in case of the infinite well. As I wrote in my answer, a state with an initially certain momentum can be prepared, but the momentum is simply not conserved in this system. If you like it better, there is HUP that prevents the initially certain momentum from conserving.

Comment: I had meant: Thus $(\hat p\psi)(x)$ is generally nonzero. Thus $\hat p$ does not preserve the boundary condition.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: First, it depends from where you approach the boundary, second, why should momentum preserve the boundary value of $\psi(L)$ if it "does not preserve" any other value within the well? How in this respect $\psi_n(L)$ is different from $\psi_n(x)$ for other $x$?

Comment: The Hilbert space of states for the square well problem only consists of the L^2 wave functions that vanish at the boundary (and outside).

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: A superposition of those wave function can describe a jump from a finite value to zero (a step-like beghaviour, no tending to zero). In other words, next to $x=L$ this superposition can be quite different from zero and represent $\hat p \psi(x<L)$.

Answer (score 3):

Applying $\hat p$ to a Hamiltonian eigenfunction gives another state indeed, but this state can be decomposed in the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. Numerically it is good everywhere except, maybe, the boundary points, so for integration purposes such a decomposition (superposition) is good. You did not obtain a diagonal matrix exclusively because you took a finite matrix for $\hat p$.

**EDIT:** Yes, at $t=0$ you can form a wave packet moving in a certain direction from "plane waves" $\exp(i k_n x)$, as usual, and then you can replace each momentum eigenfunction $\exp(i k_n x)$ with a linear combination of sines (Hamiltonian eigenfunctions $\psi_m (x)$ with the corresponding time exponentials $\exp(−i E_m t),\; t>0)$. In particular, if you choose the largest possible wave packet with a certain momentum $\psi(x,t=0)\propto \exp(-ik_n x),\;0<x<L$, then in later moments it will not keep its form because of reflections and the momentum will not conserve.

**EDIT 2:** Any standing wave $\psi(x)$ on an interval $(0,L)$ can be decomposed into a superposition of the momentum eigenfunctions $ \exp(\pm|k_n|x)$. In our case the superposition contains only two running waves with certain momenta: $\sin(k_n x)=(e^{ik_n x}-e^{-ik_n x})/(2i)$, so the momentum operator exists and there is no problem here.

Comment: I'm doing this indeed for numerical purposes. 

So technically speaking, since the matrix elements of $\hat{p}$ vanish when the difference between $m$ and $n$ increases, would taking a larger finite matrix result in the off-diagonal elements of $\hat{p}^2$ getting smaller?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 3):

A geometric approach can be achieve via an [orbifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold) construction.

I) Start with a free 1D quantum particle $\psi(x)=\psi(x+2\pi R)$ on a circle $S^1$ of circumference $2\pi R=2L$. The momentum $p=n\frac{\hbar }{R}$ is then quantized, $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$ The Hilbert space $H$ has momentum basis  $(| n\rangle)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$, where

$$\hat{p} | n\rangle~=~n\frac{\hbar }{R}| n\rangle, \qquad 
\langle n| m\rangle~=~\delta_{n,m}, \qquad n,m\in\mathbb{Z}. $$

II) The orbifold
$$I ~=~ S^1/ \mathbb{Z}_2~=~ S^1/\sim$$
is an interval of length $L$. A position $x \sim -x$ is identified with the opposite position $x\in S^1$ via a  discrete $\mathbb{Z}_2$-[group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action). To implement the two Dirichlet boundary conditions

$$\psi(x=0)~=~0~=~\psi(x=L),$$

we impose that the wave function should be odd $\psi (x) = -\psi(-x)$. This kills half of the previous Hilbert space. The $\mathbb{Z}_2$-reduced Hilbert space $H/\sim~$ has basis  $(| n\rangle_{\sim})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, where

$$|n \rangle_{\sim}~:=~\frac{|n\rangle  - |{-}n\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}=-|{-}n \rangle_{\sim}, \qquad 
{}_{\sim}\langle n| m\rangle_{\sim}~=~\delta_{n,m}- \delta_{n,-m}, \qquad 
n,m\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

We can implement the orbifold construction through a [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_%28physics%29) operator $P$,

$$P\hat{x}P~=~-\hat{x}, \qquad P\hat{p}P~=~-\hat{p}, \qquad P^2~=~{\bf 1}, \qquad P^{\dagger}~=~P.$$

A ket state $|\psi \rangle~\sim 0 $ is identified with zero if it is even, $P|\psi \rangle= |\psi \rangle$. The new basis $|n \rangle_{\sim}$ is odd, $P|n \rangle_{\sim}=-|n \rangle_{\sim}$. The absolute value $\hat{|p|}$ of the momentum operator is a $P$-even (unbounded) operator. It is diagonal in the $| n\rangle_{\sim}$ basis,
$$ \hat{|p|}~ | n\rangle_{\sim}~=~ |n|\frac{\hbar }{R}| n\rangle_{\sim},\qquad  {}_{\sim}\langle n| ~\hat{|p|}~|m\rangle_{\sim}~=~  |n| \frac{\hbar }{R}~ {}_{\sim}\langle n| m\rangle_{\sim}\qquad 
n,m\in\mathbb{Z}. $$

Answer (score 0):

The operator is well-defined for instance in the position basis the operator corresponding to $\Psi(x) = \langle x | n \rangle$ is given by the ordinary form $\hat{p} = -i \hbar (d/dx)$ **[*]**.

What happens is that $\Psi(x)$ are not eigenfunctions of the momentum operator $\hat{p}$ and, therefore, you cannot find a spectral decomposition of the operator in that basis (and, as a consequence, you cannot find a diagonal matrix).

Notice that $\Psi(x)$ are eigenfunctions of the operator $\hat{p}^2$ and it is possible to obtain the spectral decomposition

$$\hat{p}^2 = \sum p_n^2 | n \rangle  \langle n |$$

with the corresponding eigenvalues $p_n^2 = n^2h^2/4L^2$.

As a final note, it is not possible to obtain the matrix $\mathbf{p}$ from the matrix $\mathbf{p}^2$. First because the sign of $p$ is not defined and second because $\pm p$ does not correspond to a measurement of the momentum.

**[*]** By simplicity I am assuming one dimension.