Particle in an infinite potential well Quantum Mechanics
Consider a particle in an infinite potential well, If we solve for the energy using Schrodinger's equation we get the solutions, we get sine functions for wavefunction and Energy in a state is proportional to $n^2$. My questions are:
(i) What exactly is the Energy of the particle, in this case since there is no potential energy, is it just Kinetic Energy?
(ii) We know that $\psi(x)$ denotes the probability density of finding a particle at $x$, similarly there will be $\psi(p)$ (momentum) right? and $\psi(0)$ may not be zero. Now my doubt is how can the particle have variable momentum if it has fixed energy. Because $\mathrm{energy} = KE = p^2/2m$. What am I missing?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362305/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/372085/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45498/2451 and links therein.

This might help: particles need not have fixed energy

The sharp walls or delta potentials in QM are best interpreted as approximations to a smooth, potentials, which are however difficult to deal with mathematically. e.g., $U(x)=U_0\tanh(\alpha x)$ is a step potential, whereas two such steps may form a nearly squared well, which, for sufficiently large $U_0$ would be well approximated by an infinite well (for low energy states.)
If you have no problem with a square well, you may just think of a very deep square well. The solutions in the infinite well provide an estimate to what extent this approximation is valid: $E_n\ll U_0$.
Then the Hamiltonian is usual $H=K+U$, which commutes with neither position, nor momentum operators, which means that position and momentum are uncertain in the energy eigenstates.

but how can the particle have zero momentum when the total energy is non zero and potential energy is zero. If we detect a particle with zero momentum that means we detected a particle with zero energy but it can't have zero energy right?

@SaivardhanAnnam When you write "have zero momentum" you presumably mean that the expectation value of the momentum is zero. The momentum is a vector (or in 1d it is signed), so the expectation value of $p$ can be zero while the expectation value of $p^2$ is non-zero.

@SaivardhanAnnam I agree with the comment above - momentum has a probability distribution with zero mean, but finite variance. Also, if a particle has zero mean momentum it doesn't mean that it has zero energy, or even zero kinetic energy.

@RogerV Let me put it differently, in a give state we know that it has a fixed total energy. Suppose we are trying to measure the particle's momentum, it is possible to detect with zero momentum. So now that means particle don't have any kinetic energy(since momentum=0) and it doesn't have any potential energy so where did the total energy go?

@SaivardhanAnnam if you try to formulate this argument in the form of equations, you will likely see that you are using a classical formula somewhere. See also here: What does Conservation of momentum mean in Quantum mechanics?

@RogerV. Thank you for your help, I am a beginner and I did not exactly understand what you meant in that linked comment. I will try to understand it. To be honest I did not exactly understand the relation between my doubt and that comment you linked. But thanks for helping, I will try to read more about it and understand.

@SaivardhanAnnam your questions seem to rotate around conservation of energy (aka " where did the total energy go"). Classically this means that quantity $E=\frac{p^2}{2m} + U(x)$ is a constant, but quantum mechanically this doesn't make any sense: we can't even claim that $\langle \frac{p^2}{2m}\rangle = \frac{\langle p\rangle ^2}{2m}$. What conservation means is that a system in an energy eigenstate or (an eigenstate of any operator that commutes with the Hamiltonian) remains in this state indefinitely.

@SaivardhanAnnam Also, measurement perturbs the system and projects it to an eigenstate of a different Hamiltonian - this obviously changes the energy (the extra energy comes from the measurement device.)

Thank you so much, and also just to be clear


Consider a particle in an infinite potential well...
(i) What exactly is the Energy of the particle, in this case since there is no potential energy, is it just Kinetic Energy?

Yes, it is just kinetic energy.

(ii) We know that $\psi(x)$ denotes the probability density of finding a particle at $x$, similarly there will be $\psi(p)$ (momentum) right?

I would encourage you to use a different symbol for probability density in position space ($\psi(x)$) versus probability density in momentum space ($\tilde \psi(p)$), since when you use the same symbol in the same sentence, it would normally be interpreted as the same function, which $\psi(x)$ and $\tilde \psi(p)$ are not.

and $\psi(0)$ may not be zero.

See? I have no idea if you mean the probability density in space at $x=0$, or in momentum space at $p=0$. So, this part of your question is unclear.

Now my doubt is how can the particle have variable momentum if it has fixed energy. Because $\mathrm{energy} = KE = p^2/2m$. What am I missing?

The length of the momentum will be fixed in an energy eigenstate, but the direction (or sign in 1D) will not necessarily be fixed.

[from comments] but how can the particle have zero momentum when the total energy is non zero and potential energy is zero...

Your phrase "have zero momentum," is not really meaningful, unless the state is a momentum eigenstate, which an energy eigenstate is not. You can really only ask about the expectation value of the momentum in an energy eigenstate.
Energy eigenstates are standing waves
$$
\psi(x)\propto \sin(p_n x) =\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ip_n x} - e^{-ip_n x}\right)\;,
$$
which you can see are linear combinations of "forward traveling" waves
$$
e^{ip_n x}
$$
and "backward travelling" waves
$$
e^{-ip_n x}\;,
$$
with coefficients such that the overall wave function is real.
For such a standing wave the expectation value of $p$ is zero:
$$
\langle \hat p \rangle \propto \int dx \sin(p_n x)\cos(p_n x) = 0
$$
but the expectation value of $p^2$ is not zero:
$$
\langle \hat p^2 \rangle = \frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}
$$

Sorry for not being clear, I meant psi_p(0) not equal 0,  that means if we detect a particle it is possible that it has zero momentum when we detect it,assume that's what happened, now that means it doesn't have any Kinetic energy(since we detected that it has zero momentum) and also it doesn't have any potential energy so where did the energy of particle go?

@SaivardhanAnnam Why do you think any psi_p would have a non-zero value at 0? And if it did, why do you think that would correspond to a probability related to a physical momentum? As you know, the energy eigenstates are like $e^{ip_nx}-e^{-ip_nx}$, which fourier transforms to a sum of two delta function, which are only non-zero when p is $\pm p_n$... This isn't a perfect argument since the system is not translationally invariant, but that means that momentum isn't a good quantum number to begin with....
